# Поехавшая вёрстка в списке знаков

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, дизайн

Зайти в профиль, перейти во вкладку `Активность`. Далее в окне `Знаки` нажать иконку `Выберите отслеживаемый знак` - появится новое окно со списком знаков, у которого элементы снизу выходят за пределы окна.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Браузер - Opera.

Comment: Этот баг уже давно куча народа обнаружила и сообщила куда надо. Правда с никаким результатом. Быть может когда из беты выпустят, тогда и пофиксят, кто знает?