# Прогресс знаков сполз вниз

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, дизайн

В списке знаков нижний ряд вылезает за пределы окна. Думаю, это связано со сдвигом инпута для поиска, который должен бы находиться в одной строке с табами.

The last row in bages list gets out of the modal. I think, that's because of input field sliding bottom - it was planned to be on the same line with tabs.

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Такое [уже было](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/516/176217) кстати.

Comment: В очередной раз наблюдается ситуация, когда установка [meta-tag:статус-завершено] без соответствующего описания, не позволяет понять корень проблемы.

Comment: [Дефект локализации обновлённого профиля](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/201/Дефекты-локализации-обновлённого-профиля)

Comment: @Egor, там шла речь про отсутствие перевода маркера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сейчас проблема не проявляется:

> [image: следующий знак]

Судя по всему что-то откатили назад, так как [некоторые иконки](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296501/339911) снова стали серыми, но и дополнительно изменился дизайн блока через который открывается упомянутое проблемное окно:

> [image: шестерёнка]

Раньше шестерёнка была справа от прогресс бара.

Comment: Так себе поправили. Теперь на 3 строки есть скролл из-за одного-двух пикселей, шестерёнка ползает влево при клике, диалог успевает появиться до исчезновения скролла...

Comment: @Qwertiy сдвиг шестерни я тоже заметил. Но есть ещё и похуже [дефект](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296610/gear-icon-in-reputation-block-of-the-profile-is-broken).

Comment: @Qwertiy шестерни ещё раз откатили.

Comment: Но 2px всё ещё скроллится)

Answer (score 1):

Проблема точно в инпуте поиска. Специально удалил один из разделов, сразу решилась проблема.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И длина в [css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) задана в **px**, а не в **%**. Не самое лучшее решение...

```
.search input[type="text"]{
            width:585px;
            display:block;
            margin:0 8px 0 0}
```

Comment: Проценты в данном случае не помогут.

Comment: Да, я уже понял... Тогда px надо сокращать до 485

Comment: Нет, надо использовать flex или table-cell и max-width.

Comment: Мой инспектор показывает отсутствие схлопывания `margin-bottom` у `<h2 class="popup-title">` и `padding-top` у `<div class="filtering">`. Вот и получается под заголовком интервал удвоенной высоты. // cc: @Qwertiy

Comment: @Arhad, padding не схлопывается. Так и задумано.